# How to optimize performance with CREATE, PUT, and DELETE requests on MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, postman

I have a database named "reviews" with a 9.7GB size. It has a collection name `products`. I was able to optimize the `READ` request using indexing technical by running the command `db.products.ensureIndex({product_name: 1});` When I run the following command `db.products.find({product_name:"nobis"}).explain("executionStats");` in MongoDB terminal, it shows that my execution time reduces from 28334ms to 3301ms.

**I have the following 2 questions:**

**1) How do I use `explain("executionStats");` on `CREATE`, `PUT` and `DELETE` requests?** For example, I got this following error `[thread1] TypeError: db.products.insert(...).explain is not a function` when I tried to use the following insert function

```
db.products.insert({"product_id": 10000002,"product_name": "tissue","review": [{"review_id": 30000001,"user": {"user_id": 30000001,"firstname": "Peter","lastname": "Chen","gender": "Male","nickname": "Superman","email": "hongkongbboy@gmail.com","password": "123"},"opinion": "It's good","text": "It's bad","rating_overall": 3,"doesRecommended": true,"rating_size": "a size too big","rating_width": "Slightly wide","rating_comfort": "Uncomfortable","rating_quality": "What I expected","isHelpful": 23,"isNotHelpful": 17,"created_at": "2007-10-19T09:03:29.967Z","review_photo_path": [{"review_photo_id": 60000001,"review_photo_url": "https://sdcuserphotos.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/741.jpg"}, {"review_photo_id": 60000002,"review_photo_url": "https://sdcuserphotos.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/741.jpg"}]}, {"review_id": 30000002,"user": {"user_id": 30000002,"firstname": "Peter","lastname": "Chen","gender": "Male","nickname": "Superman","email": "hongkongbboy@gmail.com","password": "123"},"opinion": "It's good","text": "It's bad","rating_overall": 3,"doesRecommended": true,"rating_size": "a size too big","rating_width": "Slightly wide","rating_comfort": "Uncomfortable","rating_quality": "What I expected","isHelpful": 23,"isNotHelpful": 17,"created_at": "2007-10-19T09:03:29.967Z","review_photo_path": [{"review_photo_id": 60000003,"review_photo_url": "https://sdcuserphotos.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/741.jpg"}]}]}).explain("executionStats");
```

**2) Is there any performance Optimization method I can use for the `CREATE`, `PUT` and `DELETE` requests?** For example, I am able to use `POSTMAN` to get the response time of a `DELETE` request, but the response time takes 38.73seconds.
[image]

```
const deleteReview = (request, response) => {
    const id = parseInt(request.params.id);
    Model.ProductModel.findOneAndDelete({ "review.review_id": id}, (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            response.status(500).send(error);
        } else {
            response.status(200).send(results);
        }
    });
};
```

This is my MongoDB schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/reviews', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useCreateIndex: true });
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const productSchema = new Schema({
    product_id: { type: Number, required: true, unique: true },
    product_name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    review: [{
        review_id: { type: Number, required: true, unique: true },
        user: {
            user_id: { type: Number },
            firstname: { type: String },
            lastname: { type: String },
            gender: { type: String, enum: ['Male', 'Female', 'Other'] },
            nickname: { type: String },
            email: { type: String, required: true },
            password: { type: String, required: true },
        },
        opinion: { type: String, required: true },
        text: { type: String },
        rating_overall: { type: Number, min: 1, max: 5, required: true },
        doesRecommended: { type: Boolean, required: true },
        rating_size: { type: String, enum: ['a size too small', '1/2 a size too small', 'Perfect', '1/2 a size too big', 'a size too big'], required: true },
        rating_width: { type: String, enum: ['Too narrow', 'Slightly narrow', 'Perfect', 'Slightly wide', 'Too wide'], required: true },
        rating_comfort: { type: String, enum: ['Uncomfortable', 'Slightly uncomfortable', 'Ok', 'Comfortable', 'Perfect'], required: true },
        rating_quality: { type: String, enum: ['Poor', 'Below average', 'What I expected', 'Pretty great', 'Perfect'], required: true },
        isHelpful: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 },
        isNotHelpful: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 },
        created_at: { type: Date, required: true },
        review_photo_path: [{
            review_photo_id: { type: Number },
            review_photo_url: { type: String }
        }]
    }]
});
const ProductModel = mongoose.model('product', productSchema);
module.exports = { ProductModel };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have one, ensure you have an index of `review.review_id` on your `products` collection. You're using that to look up what to delete so it should be indexed.

I read your `deleteReview` function as deleting the product document that contains the review, not just removing the individual review -- is that what you expect?

You should be able to just `$pull` the review from the reviews array to get rid of it.

---

You can use explain on an update like so:

```
db.products.explain().update({...}, {...});
```

See: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/

You can explain:

- aggregate()
- count()
- find()
- remove()
- update()
- distinct()
- findAndModify()

Comment: Thanks. How do I refractor my `deleteReview` function to remove the individual review instead of the products collection?

Comment: You need to `$pull` an individual item (matching the ID) from the array of reviews. See: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#pull-array-of-documents

Comment: @hongkongbboy Great! You can go ahead and accept the answer using the check mark icon if the information was useful to you.

Comment: I also recently found out how to use redis cache to improve GET request, just FYI.